# Load the form without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I taking my first steps in AJAX and I having my first problem when sending a form without reloading the page. What I am trying to do is "send friend request" and I want that once the form data has been sent, the "send request" button changes to "cancel request", but it just remains the same, even if the data is sent. "Cancel request" would also be a button that would do the same procedure only the other way around and instead of inserting, it would remove.

```
<?php
  if ($estadoA['estado'] == 0){ //IF IN THE DATABASE THERE IS NO RELATIONSHIP BETWEEN USERS
    $boton="Send";
  } else {
    $boton="Cancel";
  }
  ?>

  <button id="solicitud" onclick="enviar2('<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']?>','<?php echo $_GET['id']?>')">
     <?php echo $boton;?>
  </button>
```

FUNCTIONS.JS

```
    function enviar2(emisor,receptor){
  b=$('#solicitud').html();
  if(b=="Send"){
    url="../amigos/solicitud-enviada.php";

  } else {
    url="../amigos/eliminar-solicitud.php";
  }

  cadena= "emisor=" + emisor + "&receptor=" + receptor;
  alert(url);
   $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:url,
    data:cadena,
    success:function(r){
      if (r!=0) {
        alert($('#solicitud').html());
        if (b=="Send"){
          $('#solicitud').html("Cancel");
        } else{
          $('#solicitud').html("Send");
        }
        alert($('#solicitud').html());
      } else {
        alert('error');
      }

    }
  });
  return false;
}
```

As you will see, I redirect the url according to the value obtained by the button id but it does it wrong, suppose that there is no relationship between the users, it should say "Send", once I click I have seen through an alert, which is redirected to the delete instead of being on solicitud-enviada, that is, it does not fulfill the required function, although curiously, without reloading the page and hitting the button again, it does everything correctly. That means that the initial value when loading the page is sending me an incorrect value the button id, I would appreciate if you can tell me that I am doing wrong.

Comment: It looks like you’re sending html back on your request. You probably want to send JSON instead, so that javascript can work directly with the server’s response. Be sure that you set headers as json in your php response.

Comment: Sorry for the ignorance but in what way should I do it?

Comment: Your title says "Load the form without reloading the page" but the content of your question seems to have nothing to do with it. When asking a question, keep it clear and concise without making it too confusing.

Comment: Do a `console.log(r);` right after `success: function(r){`. You’ll find that `r` is not what you’re expecting. Likewise, `b` is not likely to be what you think. HTML is probably not your best bet to pass values; look into data attributes.

Comment: a small suggestion instead of using `<?php echo $boton;?>` you can use `<?= $boton;?>`

Comment: They are right, the error is in the first conditional of functions.js that is receiving the button id incorrectly, the specific question would be What is the correct way to pass that id?